# How to correctly check the form

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please specify how to properly check the validation of the form.

My problem issue is: When I typing in input "isValidateUser" changes to true and everything works fine, but when I erase all the letters in the input, "isValidateUser" still remains true. 
Then I tried to add:

```
if(this.value == ""){
            isValidateUser = false;
        }
```

But it dosen`t work. How can it possible to make, when I erasing all letters "isValidateUser" change to false.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var isValidateUser = false;
var userName = document.querySelector(".js-type-user");
var letterOnly = /^([a-zа-яё]+|)$/i;

userName.onchange = function () {
  if (letterOnly.test(this.value)) {
    isValidateUser = true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form class="form__action" action="">
  <div class="form__user-name">
    <label class="form__label">Ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form__input js-type-user">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-mail">
    <label class="form__label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form__input js-type-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-password">
    <label class="form__label">Придумайте пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form__input js-type-pass">
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__check" checked>
  <label class="form__text">Регистрируясь, вы подтверждаете, что вам уже исполнилось <br> 18 лет и вы ознакомились с условиями пользования сайтом. </label>
  <div class="page__transition page__transition-blue">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-blue-disabled">продолжить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` branch to ensure that `isValidateUser` gets set correctly (no matter what the validation results in) upon each invocation of the event handler.

```js
var userName = document.querySelector(".js-type-user");
var isValidateUser = false;  
var letterOnly = /^([a-zа-яё]+|)$/i;

userName.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  if (letterOnly.test(this.value)) {
    isValidateUser = true;
  } else {
    isValidateUser = false;
  }
  console.log(isValidateUser);
});
```

```html
<form class="form__action" action="">
  <div class="form__user-name">
    <label class="form__label">Ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form__input js-type-user">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-mail">
    <label class="form__label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form__input js-type-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-password">
    <label class="form__label">Придумайте пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form__input js-type-pass">
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__check" checked>
  <label class="form__text">Регистрируясь, вы подтверждаете, что вам уже исполнилось <br>
                        18 лет и вы ознакомились с условиями пользования сайтом.
                    </label>
  <div class="page__transition page__transition-blue">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-blue-disabled">продолжить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There's a specific scenario that doesn't work. If you enter for example a word like 'a' and erase that, isValidateUser will be 'true'. I've changed the regular expression to achieve 'false' in that case.

Comment: @ThiagoChagas That's true, but the question wasn't about the correctness of the regular expression, so I didn't scrutinize that.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentions you're only ever setting the value to true (and never back to false). However you're regexp is also matching against an empty string.

See below a working example. I've removed the unrelated HTML.

```js
var isValidateUser = false;
var userName = document.querySelector(".js-type-user");
var letterOnly = /^([a-zа-яё]+|)[^\s]$/i;

userName.onchange = function () {
  isValidateUser = letterOnly.test(this.value);
  
  document.getElementById('isUsernameValid').textContent = isValidateUser;
};
```

```html
<div class="form__user-name">
    <label class="form__label">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form__input js-type-user">
  </div>
  
<div id="isUsernameValid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found two problems:

1)Your regex returns "true" with empty string.

2) When the "isValidateUser" is true, the variable doesn't assume 'false' anymore.

You can achieve with this: (I have changed the Regex and have used trim)

```js
var isValidateUser = false;
var userName = document.querySelector(".js-type-user");
var letterOnly = /^[\s\[a-zа-яё]+$/i;

userName.onchange = function () {
  isValidateUser = letterOnly.test(this.value.trim()); 
  console.log(isValidateUser); 
};
```

```html
<form class="form__action" action="">
  <div class="form__user-name">
    <label class="form__label">Ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form__input js-type-user">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-mail">
    <label class="form__label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form__input js-type-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-password">
    <label class="form__label">Придумайте пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form__input js-type-pass">
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__check" checked>
  <label class="form__text">Регистрируясь, вы подтверждаете, что вам уже исполнилось <br> 18 лет и вы ознакомились с условиями пользования сайтом. </label>
  <div class="page__transition page__transition-blue">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-blue-disabled">продолжить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```